# Select box option event on Foundation

Tags: jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I am working on a selection box element in foundation, and I am trying to figure out to make a single selected option open to open a specified modal.

For example if I selected Saab, I would want a specific modal to open. And if I selected Audi, another modal specific to Audi should open. Below is my code snippet.

```
<select>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option> 
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please this check this code, this may be solved you problem

// JS code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      var dialog1 = $( "#dialog-form1" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 350,
            modal: true
          });
       var dialog2 = $( "#dialog-form2" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 350,
            modal: true
          });

      $('#selectId').on('change', function () {
        dialog1.dialog( "close" );
        dialog2.dialog( "close" );
         var selectVal = $("#selectId option:selected").val();
         if(selectVal == 'saab'){
            dialog1.dialog( "open" );
            // code
         }
         else if(selectVal == 'audi'){
            dialog2.dialog( "open" );
            //code
         }
    });
});
```

//html code

```
<select id="selectId">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option> 
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<div id="dialog-form1">
</div>

<div id="dialog-form2" >
</div>
```